# Setting objects into edit mode often seems to fail in python script

Tags: python

I am only just starting to learn/use python in blender.  I have the following script

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:

    if obj.name[0:4] == "Text" and obj.type == "MESH":

        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        print(bpy.context.mode)


        #bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
        #print(bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(0.0001))
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

I am trying to work out why I keep getting a context error for bpy.ops.mesh.select_all so I added the `print(bpy.context.mode)` line and commented out the line that was failing (plus the next line which takes action)

what I get in the console (this script is being run from the console rather than run in place) is a mixture of 'OBJECT' and 'EDIT_MESH' outputs.. suggesting that mode_set is failing a lot of the time.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using blender 2.68a on Windows 7.

**Edit** I discovered the actual cause of my issue (hinted at by Adhi's edit) and wanted to add it to my post so that others can take something away from this - the objects that were not being switched into edit mode were on another layer.  Once I made all layers active my script was able to switch all objects into edit mode.  So basically an object in an unselected layer cannot be set into edit mode.

I am also grateful for the other help and suggestions, they have been useful to help me learn python scripting within blender which is something I would love to use more extensively.

Comment: can you give more info about your environmnt (os, Blender v. #)? How many objects you have?

Comment: Just with a quick glance at your code, it appears like you're trying to set multiple objects in Edit mode at the same time. This is not currently possible.

Comment: OS- Windows 7. Blender 2.68a.  I'm not sure exactly how many objects.  There are approximately 400

Comment: for what its worth -- I ran your script on 1536 cubes with duplicated vertices (24576 verts total) and it went through fine (reducing verts to 12288). The only change was print(bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.00001)). Blender 1.68a, mac os x mountain lion

Comment: As a side note: You can use `obj.name.starswith("Text")`, and note that `bpy.context.mode` and `bpy.context.object.mode` differ, see [bug tracker](https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=498&aid=30911&group_id=9).

Comment: Another side note:  [Using bmesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68133/15543), can often remove the need to swap mode and context object altogether.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/setting-objects-into-edit-mode-often-seems-to-fail-in-python-script#comment5884_3441) by dimus, your problem is solved by adding keyword to the [`mesh.remove_doubles`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles) operator's first argument, meant as `threshold` property value. With that little bug fixed, your script works properly.

What causes the error is that, **keyword arguments** are used to set operator properties, and **positional arguments** to set how the operator is called (further explained in the [API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.html#keywords-and-positional-arguments)). By not using a keyword for the first argument, you're turning it into a *positional* argument, thus interpreted as operator execution context which is an error.

**EDIT**: Another possible error is iterating over [`bpy.data.objects`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.objects), which comprises of all objects *in every scene* in a file. The script is bound to fail if there's more than one scene in a file containing a `MESH` object, because it'll try to make object from a different scene the active object of current scene which is contextually incorrect. You should iterate over [`bpy.context.scene.objects`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.objects) instead.

Here's the amended code, can't see any other bug:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.layers = [True] * 20 # Show all layers

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        scene.objects.active = obj

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.0001)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: Actually I hadn't got as far as correcting the remove_doubles function because the function that was failing was select_all.  it was failing whenever the object had not managed to enter edit mode.

Comment: @MrVimes: I missed another bug :) It's still not related to `mode_set`, though. Can't see cases where that one could fail. Showing the Outliner space of your test file would help.

Comment: I have marked yours as accepted because your edit pointed me in the right direction for finding out what was actually going on - the objects that were not going into edit mode were on another layer.  I shift-clicked all the layers with objects in them and ran the script again - it was then able to switch *all* objects into edit mode.

Comment: So there's another one. Blind troubleshooting sure is fun :D Edited again for completeness.

Comment: Since Blender 2.80 `scene.objects.active = obj` no longer works. Use `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I, too, have had issues in the past using the mesh `select_all` operator from within Edit mode. As an alternative, try looping through all of the vertices and setting their `select` property to `True`. Then, switch into Edit mode before doing the Remove Doubles operator. Your code should look something like this:

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:

    if obj.name[0:4] == "Text" and obj.type == 'MESH':

        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
        for vert in obj.vertices:
            vert.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.0001)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this subject and want to post my solution, removing doubles of object with given objectname :

```
def myremovedoubles(objectname, mergedist):
    obj = None
    try:
        obj = bpy.data.objects[objectname]
    except ( RuntimeError ):
        pass  
    if (obj != None): 
        try:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.data.objects[objectname].select = True            
            scene.objects.active = obj
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(mergedist=mergedist)
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            return True
        except ( RuntimeError ):
            pass  
    return False
```

this function will return True if executed without RuntimeError, meaning the remove_doubles function was executed

it doesn't crash when the object doesn't exist
it sets the object as the only active (and selected)
it switches between modes, assuming mode='OBJECT' is the default

Comment: Not a fan of the try catch, especially when IMO not required.  For instance `obj = bpy.data.objects.get(objectname)` removes the need for your first `try`.

Comment: and scene is not available when this function is called from another filen   and mergedist doesn't always work : more often the name of that argument is threshold.   and when using something like def do(func, **args) I get an unexpected list of unavailable context properties : bpy.context.* seems unavailable. If I pass bpy.context.scene as argument other errors come up.    The try/catch thing is just a point of view, I assume the .get function loops the available, so probably takes more action

Comment: Rubbish.  Because code fails silently, it hasn't worked.   All the cases you mention will just cause your code to fail silently.  Also, trying to set an object from data (`bpy.data.objects`) as context object,  if it is not linked to the context scene will cause an error,  which is an easily avoided basic logic error IMO.  Get the object from `context.scene.objects` Finally, here is the [Blender API Best Practice "point of view" on try / except](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_best_practice.html#use-try-except-sparingly)

Comment: On a lighter note, using bmesh, removes the need for edit mode and `bpy.ops...` altogether.  [Example here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68133/15543)

Comment: @user42646 it's great that you've tried to post an answer. This is not a good way to solve the problem, and as batFINGER points out `bmesh` is the far more modern way to solve this. That's a danger and posting new answers to old questions and that's why new answers to old question pop up fresh in the review queue. Anyway I gave you an up vote just for "effort". Hint: In the beginning it's easier to get reputation (points) asking questions unless you have a pretty good answer. Welcome to stackexchange! If you haven't already, why don't you [take the tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour)