# Why a scene render might have many very dark triangle artifacts?

Tags: mesh, light, artifacts

It was imported from obj and the scene has some `environment` light and a lot of `sun` light (the only way to make shadows more contrast I found).

[image]

`.blend` file: https://yadi.sk/d/UEUud0Y93HWBUH

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edit mode press <kbd>A</kbd>, so that the whole mesh is selected. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (this fixes the normals of an object, normal essentially tell the render engine which way the face is facing). Then press <kbd>W</kbd> and select *delete doubles*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works like magic! Could you please also specify name of an operation that is performed when you do `Ctrl+N`?

Comment: wonder why [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68124/36700) answer might not work here; it seems like they do very same things

Comment: I'm sure though, I"m not the best with python

Comment: @Ben Usman CTRL+N is the shortcut to (edit mode) mesh > normals > recalculate outside